# echo into grafts does not work

Tags: git, .git-info-grafts

I have a big repository with more than 300,000 commits. I wanna work just with recent commits. So, I used the following command:

echo "" > .git/info/grafts

But it does not work, since after that I ran git log, again it returned all the commits. The NEW-ROOT-SHA1 that I passed is also on master branch.

Comment: Why are you using grafts?  I'm not very familiar with that part of git, but a cursory googling suggests that the grafts feature is mostly useful for interoperating with other SCMs.  You don't mention any other systems in your question, though...

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on leaving the main repository alone and limiting your local clone to just a few commits, you could use the following command to get only the last 12 commits:

`git clone [location] --depth 12`